# Accumulo init : ERROR: Unable to find Hadoop Configuration class on classpath, check configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, accumulo

When I run `accumulo init` I get this Error:

```
2021-01-14 14:00:12,708 [start.Main] ERROR: Unable to find Hadoop Configuration class on classpath, check configuration.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader$1.loadClass(AccumuloClassLoader.java:204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

I configured Accumulo according to the Accumulo Documentation.
Hadoop and Zookeeper are running.

I ran `/bin/accumulo classpath`
output:

```
home/sabi/accumulo-2.0.0/conf:/home/sabi/accumulo-2.0.0/lib/*:/home/sabi/hadoop-2.10.1//share/*:/home/sabi/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin//*:/home/sabi/hadoop-2.10.1//share/hadoop/client/*
```

I installed hadoop in the folder `/home/sabi/hadoop-2.10.1`.

I added

```
## Hadoop installation
export HADOOP_HOME="${HADOOP_HOME:-/hadoop-2.10.1}"
## Hadoop configuration
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-${HADOOP_HOME}/share/*}"
```

to the file `accumulo-2.0.0/conf/accumulo-env.sh`.

How can Hadoop Configuration Class be found on classpath?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run Accumulo 2.x with Hadoop 2.10.1. Accumulo 2.x was designed to be used with Hadoop 3 only, not Hadoop 2. I don't know if that is your problem or not, but it could be. See also other generic answers for how to resolve ClassNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/search?q=classnotfoundexception+stackoverflow

Comment: Can you run accumulo? Did you just follow the apache documentation? Or did you read sth else? I am struggling since days!

Comment: Thanks! I deinstalled hadoop 2.10.1 and installed 3.2.2 instead, it was not the problem though. I added export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH://home/sabi/hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/common/* to the file .bashrc and that solved it. I just have new Errors now....